# Why is $\int \frac{du}{u}$ equal to $\ln|u|$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

> Why is $\displaystyle \int\dfrac{dx}{x} = \ln|x|$?

What I am asking is about the absolute value. I know that it is used so that $\ln x$ will not have an undefined value for $x < 0$. How can we recheck if this is the correct antiderivative? We take the derivative.

Let $f(x) = \ln|x|$ and $u = |x|$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{df}{dx} &= \dfrac{df}{du}\cdot\dfrac{du}{dx} \\ &=\frac{1}{u}\cdot\frac{x}{|x|} \\ &= \frac{1}{|x|}\cdot\frac{x}{|x|} \\ &=\frac{x}{|x|^{2}}\end{align*}$$

This seems odd. What did I do wrong? Should I get the derivative for $x < 0$ and $x > 0$ separately?

---

Edit: This might be similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841549/888233), but what I am asking for is confirming that the antiderivative obtained is correct by taking the derivative.

Comment: I thought $\ln 0$ is defined, so I included it. Should I not?

Comment: $\ln 0$ is not defined.

Comment: You don't have to do it separately but if you want for $x<0$ we have $\ln|x|=\ln(-x) $ and $(\ln(-x))'=-\frac{1}{-x}=\frac1 x$

Comment: Oh, sorry. My brain just skipped and thought that it was. I was thinking of $\ln 1$ which is $0$, then just made $\ln 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\dfrac x{|x|^2}=\dfrac x{x^2}=\dfrac1x$, you get that $\dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac1x$.

Anyway, the simplest approach consists in using the fact that$$\ln|x|=\begin{cases}\ln(x)&\text{ if }x>0\\\ln(-x)&\text{ if }x<0.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned before, it is simply a matter of defining a primitive in the largest possible set. Taking
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
\ln x, & x>0\\ \ln (-x), & x <0
\end{cases}
$$

you can check that $f'(x)=\frac 1x$, for all $x \ne 0$. As a side comment, saying that $\int \frac 1x dx = \ln|x| + C$ is not entirely correct, we should in  fact say the family of all primitives of $\frac 1x$ is

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
\ln x + C_1, & x>0\\ \ln (-x) + C_2, & x <0.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{df}{dx} &= \dfrac{df}{du}\cdot\dfrac{du}{dx} \\ &=\frac{1}{u}\cdot\frac{|x|}{x} \\ &= \frac{1}{|x|}\cdot\frac{|x|}{x} \\ &=\frac{1}{x}\end{align*}$$

PS: $x\neq0$

Comment: The derivative of $|x|$ is $\frac{x}{|x|}$, not $\frac{|x|}{x}$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No: the both are synonyms $\frac{|x|}{x}=\frac{x}{|x|}\ \forall x\neq0$, depending how you calculate it you get the one or the other result, but they are the same.

Comment: Ok, fair enough